# Would it be appropriate to use Singles for RxAndroidBle reads and writes?

Tags: rx-android, rxandroidble

I'm still learning the Reactive paradigm, and just came across the `Single<T>` and `SingleSubscriber<T>` classes. It strikes me that these might be appropriate for "one-time" operations like reading or writing a control characteristic via BLE. 
Does this make sense? What are the pros and cons? Would it require implementation by the authors of RxAndroidBle? Any explanation & discussion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `RxAndroidBle` library was started there were no `Single` nor `Completable` classes in the `RxJava` library. 
These constructs would fit well in the `RxAndroidBle` and are planned but it would need a bit of work from the library's author and would change the API - a version bump to 2.0.0 would be required.